# Como generar un único ID de una venta , de modo que el usuario pueda consultarlas las diferentes compras que realizo en una base de dato

Tags: base-de-datos, id

estoy realizando un e-commerce, con un carrito de compras y  me gustaría pedirles su apoyo para saber como puede un usuario identificar las diferentes compras que ha realizado, es decir me gustaría guardar en una base de datos las diferentes compras que un cliente realizo, pero no encuentro la manera de generar un único código para cada compra, de tal modo que el usuario pueda ver sus diferentes canastas. He pensado en concatenar el usuario o correo con la fecha, pero habría un error si es que el usuario realiza varias compras en día o en la misma hora ya que nos sería la manera correcta de agruparlas.

También se me ocurrió utilizar alguna función desde el gestor de base de datos  que genere un único código de la compra y que cuando el usuario quiera ver sus compras que esta las agrupe por id, pero me enfrente a la interrogante de ¿y como voy a saber a que id  genero el gestor de base de datos y con que id estoy relacionando la venta?

Otra forma que se me ocurrió es que en la misma base de datos crear un campo que almacene el numero de venta del cliente de modo que cuando el cliente haga una compra, el sistema consulte el numero de venta y cree un código a partir de ese dato.

```
   $numeroVenta= 1;
    $usuario ="Miguel_Olvera";
    $idVenta = "V-".$numeroVenta.$numeroVenta;
echo "V-Miguel_Olvera1";
```

(No recuerdo si así se hacía en php)
En conclusión yo quiero saber como puedo guardar las ventas que hizo cada usuario, como agruparlas, (ya sea generando un id o de otra forma)  , de modo tal que estas puedan ser después consultadas por el mismo.

Nota: sino fui claro, puedo dar más detalles.

Comment: En PHP, tras realizar una inserción con la clase `mysqli`, dispones de la propiedad `$mysqli->insert_id` que te facilita el `id` que le ha asignado el `AUTO_INCREMENT`. Crea las tablas que necesites y, si tienes alguna dificultad, modifica tu pregunta incorporando tu dataset y lo que hayas intentado

Comment: @DavidJP parece viable lo que me comentas, pero tengo una duda, que sucede si dos personas realizan al mismo tiempo una compra y obtienen el mismo valor que le asigna mysql con el AUTO_INCREMENT o eso no llegaría a suceder? ósea ¿no llegaría  a suceder que dos registros tengan el mismo id si utilizo lo que me sugieres?

Comment: Puedes quedarte tranquilo, que no sucederá: los `id` los asigna la base de datos y no cada una de las instancias del script de PHP que puedan estar ejecutándose simultáneamente.

Comment: Te agradezco muchísimo @DavidJP , ya he investigado lo que me dices y sí me sirve, muchas gracias.